# Facebook send dialog: adding query string parameters to the link

Tags: facebook, url, send

I'm trying to send a message with a link that included query string parameters, but after sending the message the parameters are automatically omitted. 
Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the parameters you are sending.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it on the example send dialog. All i did was urlencode the query parameters.

[Example Send Dialog with Query parameters (google.com/?q=Test)](http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&name=Google%20Test%20Search&link=http://www.google.com/%3Fq%3Dtest&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response)